# some python3 behavior i am unable to understood

Tags: python-3.x

I have used following codes.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from random import randint, randrange,choice, shuffle

def random_array(low, high, step, size):
    lst = []
    while len(lst)<size:
        nexts = randrange(low, high, step)
        if nexts in lst:continue
        lst.append(nexts)
    return lst
def find_pair_from_two_list(a, b, val):
    b_dict = defaultdict(int)
    for i,v in enumerate(b): b_dict[v] = i
        for v in a:
            if (val - v) in b_dict:
                return v, val-v
     return -1, -1

 arr1 = random_array(1, 100, 1, 99)
 arr2 = random_array(1, 100, 1, 99)
 val1 = choice(arr1)
 val2 = choice(arr2)
 val = val1 + val2     
 print(find_pair_from_two_list(arr1,arr2, val))
```

However if i change size value in

```
 arr1 = random_array(1, 100, 1, 99)
 arr2 = random_array(1, 100, 1, 99)
```

upto 99 it works instantly but if i change any of the size value to 100 or more it just seems to hang in there.
I am curious to know why this is happening.I mean it works well till 99 but what causes it to hang for even 100.

Comment: Why don't you just make a `random.sample` of the range, rather than looping?

Comment: random numbers w/o duplicates?

Comment: added perf testing for my solution and @jonrsharpe s suggestion - his suggestions kicks mine performance wise _sigh_

Comment: Thanks for all the interest. I am overwhelmed. However my query and doubt was if i use size upto 99 it gives me instant result. when i change it to 100 just 1 number ahead it hangs on there. I have learned  quite a few handy tips from your all answers . Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

**Why is yours slow:**

Using  `arr1 = random_array(1, 100, 1, 100)` your method can take lots of time to draw the last missing numbers because you draw new random values over and over and discard them when they are already inside your resultlist:

```
while len(lst)<size:
    nexts = randrange(low, high, step)
    if nexts in lst:continue      # discards already inside numbers
    lst.append(nexts)
return lst
```

With inputs like this you essentially draw "all" possible numbers until done and the more your result contains the longer it takes to draw another "fitting" one.

You can even produce endless loops if your `range(low,high,steps)` has less total values then your `size` demands.

```
(1,100,5,100) # => only 20 in this range with this stepper -> endless loop
```

---

**Possible simplification (not optimal)**

You could simplyfy and speedup the code by:

```
import random

def  random_array(low, high, step, size):
     poss = list(range(low,high,step))     # this does not contain duplicates
     random.shuffle(poss)                  # shuffle it
     return poss[:size]                    # return size (or all) elements from it

print(random_array(1,100,1,10))
```

This code will return if you specify "wrong" combinations to it, but the resulting list is then ***shorter*** as whatever you specified as `size`.

---

**Even better**

[jonsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe)s suggestion to use

```
random.sample(range(low,high,step),size)
```

like so:

```
def ra(low,high,step,size):
    return random.sample(range(low,high,step),size)
```

---

**Performance test**

Performancewise they the `random.sample` outperforms mine for big lists easily:

```
import random

def  random_array(low, high, step, size):
     poss = list(range(low,high,step))
     random.shuffle(poss)
     return poss[:size]


def ra(low,high,step,size):
   return random.sample(range(low,high,step),size)

import timeit

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit

    # create 100 times 495 randoms of range (1,1000000,22)

    print(timeit.timeit("ra(1,1000000,22,495)", setup="from __main__ import ra",number = 10000))

    print(timeit.timeit("random_array(1,1000000,22,495)", setup="from __main__ import random_array",number = 10000))
```

Output:

```
1.1825043768664596  # random.sample(...) of range(...)
92.12594874871951   # mine
```

Reason probably being I create actual `list`s from `range`s, `random.sample` uses `range`s with iterators smartly...

Doku:

- https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/random.html
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html